# Reversing percentage ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using Matplotlib and would like to invert the tick labels (not the axis itself) of an axis. I am aware of PercentFormatter(), but there doesn't seem to be a way to reverse tick labels once it is called upon.

I've tried manually setting the ticks with a list of reversed percentage values for the max Y axis value as such:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

positions = [
  [4, 20, 12, 5],
  [1, 10, 2, 9],
  [8, 100, 40, 7],
  [0, 15, 5, 3]  
  ]
line_pos = 8

for line, len_line, g, t in positions:
  gRel = g/len_line
  tRel = t/len_line
  pos = line_pos - line 
  plt.plot([gRel, gRel +tRel], [pos, pos])

l = [(j/line_pos)*100 for j in reversed(range(0, line_pos))]

locs, labels = plt.yticks()         
plt.yticks(locs, l)
plt.show()
```

but some markers appear outside of the ticks bounds.[image]

How would I go about reversing these labels correctly, with the correct percentage per tick label?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Would you mind providing a [mcve]? Else one cannot see how this goes wrong.

Comment: What is `nb`  ? What exactly is undesired about the result?

Comment: This was a mistake, now fixed. As I said in my question's description, some markers appear outside the bounds of labelled ticks. Ideally the first tick would be 0, the last 100 top to bottom

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is more what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

positions = [
  [4, 20, 12, 5],
  [1, 10, 2, 9],
  [8, 100, 40, 7],
  [0, 15, 5, 3]  
  ]
line_pos = 8

for line, len_line, g, t in positions:
  gRel = g/len_line
  tRel = t/len_line
  pos = line_pos - line 
  plt.plot([gRel, gRel +tRel], [pos, pos])


locs = list(range(line_pos+1))
l = [(j/line_pos)*100 for j in reversed(locs)]   

plt.yticks(locs, l)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me, thank you so much ! :)